# How to map multiple @OneToOne associations from same table

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

I currently have a simple application where properties of my Container class map to database columns.

Today...

```
@Entity
class Container {
    @Column
    private BigDecimal propertyA;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal propertyB;
}
```

I'm trying to expand my design to allow multiple values to be stored together for each logical property. I'd now like to store 5 values for each property to represent their uncertainty (some may be null)

At the database schema level this could be represented like this. I don't believe each uncertainty requires it's own id since the combination of (container_id, data_field) is unique.

```
CREATE TABLE container (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE uncertainty (
    container_id bigint not null,
    data_field varchar(100) not null,
    maximum decimal null,
    upside decimal null,
    reference decimal null,
    downside decimal null,
    minimum decimal null,
    primary key (container_id, data_field),
    constraint fk_container_id foreign key (container_id) references container (id),
);
```

There would be one row in table `uncertainty` for each property in `Container` that required this functionality.

In the example above there would two rows in `uncertainty` with the `data_field` values being `propertyA` and `propertyB`.

Something like this would be convenient..

```
@Entity
class Container {

    // How do I map multiple @OneToOne relationships to the uncertainty table based on e.g. the value of data_field = 'propertyA' or data_field = 'propertyB'

    private Uncertainty propertyA;
    private Uncertainty propertyB;
}

@Entity
class Uncertainty {

    // Do I need fields here to represent the composite primary key (containerId, data_field)?

    @Column
    private BigDecimal maximum;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal upside;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal reference;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal downside;

    @Column
    private BigDecimal minimum;
}
```

What is the best way of mapping this relationship with JPA/Hibernate?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need a composite key, you need an @Id

```
@Entity
class Uncertainty {

// Do I need fields here to represent the composite primary key (containerId, data_field)?

@Id
private int id;

@Column
private BigDecimal maximum;

@Column
private BigDecimal upside;

@Column
private BigDecimal reference;

@Column
private BigDecimal downside;

@Column
private BigDecimal minimum;
```

}

And the references (propertyA, propertyB etc) should be:

```
@Entity
class Container {

// How do I map multiple @OneToOne relationships to the uncertainty table based on e.g. the value of data_field = 'propertyA' or data_field = 'propertyB'

    @OneToOne
    private Uncertainty propertyA;
    @OneToOne
    private Uncertainty propertyB;
}
```

however of course you will need to know the exact number of the objects you want to reference

Comment: Thanks. I know the number at compile time. There will be a fixed set of properties like this. This is certainly more like the end result I’m looking for. However, I’m still I confused about the @Id though. More specifically, don’t I need to reference data_field somewhere?

Comment: You assign an ID for each Uncertainty object, it can be auto generated: @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) and then, on each referencing object you assign for example: propertyA = new Uncertainty(5) - will point to Uncertainty object with ID 5. You will have to manage those objects and know their IDs somehow, of course. You can also retrieve them using JPA and assign them

Comment: I was hoping to make use of the fact that (container_id, data_field) is already a key and describe that somehow in the mapping. It seems it's not possible or I'm approaching things from the wrong angle.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described is a OneToMany relationship, where each Container has a collection of Uncertainty.

```
@Entity
class Container {
    @JoinColumn(name = "container_id")
    private Collection<Uncertainty> properties;
    ...
}

@Entity
class Uncertainty {
    ...
}
```

Nothing additional is needed in Uncertainty to map this.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to avoid bundling them all together as I'd have to keep filtering the Collection to find the values for propertyA or propertyB etc. I'd really like to map them to single variables in the Container object. Is this not possible?

Comment: this is possible if you know the exact number of Uncertainty objects during compile time.. You will have to have this exact number of references, just like you wrote yourself : private Uncertainty propertyA;
    private Uncertainty propertyB and so on. Also your Uncertainty class needs an id (annotated as such) .. and all the references to it would be OneToOne